# Prove that there exists at most one vector $v$ orthogonal to $p-q$ and such that $x$ belongs to the range of $\alpha_{p,q,v}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

For any triple $p,q,v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ the path $$\alpha_{p,q,v}:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R^n},\alpha_{p,q,v}(t)=(1-t)p+tq+t(1-t)v$$

Is a parabolic arc with endpoints $p,q$.
Prove that if $p\neq q$, for any $x\in \mathbb{R^n}- \lbrace p,q \rbrace$ there exists at most one vector $v$ orthogonal to $p-q$ and such that $x$ belongs to the range of $\alpha_{p,q,v}$

I try to imagine it in the plane and fix $x$, and draw the points $p,q$ and the vector $-q$ and draw the vector $p-q$ and try to identify the way of build the vector $v$ orthogonal to $p-q$ but Simply any construction come to my thoughts, I have 3 hours trying it, but any idea comes.

If someone can give me a suggestion, hint, or idea that was very helpful,

Comment: What I don't understand: we chose any $x$ different from $p$ and $q$, but on the other hand you want that $x$ belongs to the range of $\alpha$.  What am I missing?

Comment: Since the path pass for $p$, then for $v$ and end in $q$. Then fix $x$ and you should find $v$ such that $v$ orthogonal to $p-q$ and such that $x$ belongs the path $\alpha$

Comment: Misread: $x$ is supposed to lie on $\alpha$ and $x$ is not an endpoint of $\alpha$.

Comment: I think that is  not necessary that $x$ lie in $\alpha$

Comment: I was trying do more draws for understand more the problem and try to do the construction, but any idea comes to me .

Comment: I'm puzzled.  You wrote "*and such that $x$ belongs to the range of $\alpha_{p,q,v}$*".  Now does $x$ belong to $\alpha$ or not?

Comment: I'm puzzled too with the problem, following my understanding of the problem I think that $x$ not necessary lie in $\alpha$

Comment: But you have literally written "$x$ belongs to the range of $\alpha_{p,q,v}$", so which one is it?

Comment: When you fix $x$, it point not necessary belongs to $\alpha$, and in fact you should can proof that exists $v$ such that it orthogonal to $p-q$ and too makes that the path $\alpha$  contains $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a suitable translation we assume that $q=0$.  For any  $x$ (not necessarily belonging to $\alpha$) (and not parallel to $p$ as in this case clearly no solution exists) the usual suspect for $v$ would be a vector parallel to
$$\frac{\|p\|^2}{\langle x,p\rangle}x-p,$$
that is
$$v=k\cdot\left(\frac{\|p\|^2}{\langle x,p\rangle}x-p\right)$$
for some constant $k$.

Now we force $k$ such $x$ belongs to $\alpha$ setting
$$x=p(1-t)+t(1-t)k\cdot\left(\frac{\|p\|^2}{\langle x,p\rangle}x-p\right).$$

Multiply by $p$ to get
$$1-t=\frac{\langle x,p\rangle}{\|p\|^2}$$
and subtitute that $t$.

We want $0\leq t\leq1$, so we must have
$$0\leq\frac{\langle x,p\rangle}{\|p\|^2}\leq1.$$

Now multiply out and determine the coefficient of $p$.  As $p$ and $x$ are linearly independent the coefficient of $p$ must vanish, which yields to
$$k=\frac{\|p\|^2}{\|p\|^2-\langle x,p\rangle},$$
if $p$ and $p-x$ aren't orthogonal (in which case there is no solution).  Hence finally
$$v=\frac{\|p\|^2}{\|p\|^2-\langle x,p\rangle}\cdot\left(\frac{\|p\|^2}{\langle x,p\rangle}x-p\right).$$

Comment: Great form of find $v$ I can prove that exists at most one by contradiction, but I never can find $v$.Tanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, it was a lot of fun!